# Stacking compasses and what happens

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

A fellow science teacher had his compasses stacked on top of each other. He is teaching orienteering to his MO Science class.    He noticed that they moved away from North and that each one would align in the opposite direction of the one below it.  What is happening?

Answer (score 5):

Two North's don't want to align next to each other - it is a lower energy state for one North end to be next to South's on the other compasses. Each compass needle is a little magnet, that aligns with the Earth's field to reduce its energy. Close together, those little magnets are stronger than the Earth's field, so they respond to each other